# What are some good win rates for heads-up and 6-max SnGs? (regular or turbo, but not hyper)

Tags: sng

I usually only play heads-up SnGs or 6-max SnGs, with speed being regular or turbo, never hyper.

In order to be profitable, what percentage of games should one be winning?

For the heads-up, I read online that it should be at least 60 %, and preferably 65 % or close to 70 %. Is this true?

For the 6-max, I have not found nothing online. Also, I think we need two percentages here: one which tells us how often we should end in the money (top 2), and another which tells us how often we should actually win it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically winrate is used for cash games. Your metric for tournaments is **ROI** (return of investment).

1) **How to calculate ROI:**

ROI=Net Winnings / Total Investment=

{(Total Winnings)-(Total Buyins incl Rake)} / (Total Buyins incl Rake)

*Example:*

So assume that you have played 100 SNGs with a buy in of $5+$0.5 and won a total of 700$.

Then: Total Buyins including Rake=100*(5+0.5)=$550
Total Winnings=$700
And your ROI= (700-550) / 550 =0.27=27%

2) **Converting ROI to Winrate and Winrate to ROI**

> Winrate=(Buyin w. rake)*(1+ROI) / Prizepool
>
> ROI=(Prizepool*Winrate - Buyin w. Rake) / Buyin w. Rake

Source: [TwoPlusTwo](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/185/heads-up-sng-spin-gos/converting-roi-winrate-663452/)

3) **Good winrate for HU and 6max SNG?**

Well, that depends on many factors (stakes, multitabling, etc.). Lots of [regs](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/185/heads-up-sng-spin-gos/good-roi-994507/) will argue that for HU a good ROI is around 3-8%, i.e. winrate of 56-60% (win 6 out of 10 games you play for 5+0.5 HEADSUP SNG)

[Here](https://www.tournamentterminator.com/tournament-strategy/roi-bankroll/sng-roi-possible/) is a more general guide including all kind of tournaments (including 6max that you are asking). Stakes you are playing are taken into account, so it states that for low stakes you can achieve a ROI of around 15%, but as you go up stakes you drop down to a ROI of 5%

If you want a good comparison, I would suggest using [SHARKSCOPE](https://www.sharkscope.com/), search for top-players in your area (like top 10 players in $3.5 HeadsUp sit and go tournaments), check their stats and compare.

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that these numbers are for regular SNGs. If you are playing Fast/Turbo/Hyper-Turbos, your ROI might be affected. In fast tournaments you play more games in the same time, so basically you increase the volume at the expense of winrate (to put it simply you win less often, but play more games), so this could work in a either a costly or very profitable way,depending of course on your gameplay.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you shouldn't focus on your win rate, but on your decision making. These sit & go's are high very variance, win rate after even 100 sit & go's are not accurate at all. But to answer your question:

The **heads-up** win rate to be profitable really depends on the rake percentage. Your rate to be nor winning nor losing can be calculated like this:

Win rate = entry fee / 1st place prize

The win rate should usually be around 52-56%. If it is higher than this I recommend you to find another format or client.

Now **6-max** is a little more difficult, since 2 spots pay. To make this a bit more easy we should assume that if you get heads-up you will win 50% of the time. Your top 2 win rate can be calculated as follows:

Win rate = entry fee / (1/2 * 1st place + 2nd place)

This number should be around 35-39%.

Comment: Wrong and wrong

Comment: @paparazzi and you call me rude, haha. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score -3):

Well second typically does not pay heads up.

rate * first = entry

rate = entry / first

SNG if you make the top 2 then can assume will win 1/2 the time.

rate x (first + second) / 2 = entry

rate = entry x 2 / (first + second)

Comment: Wow 3 down votes to a correct answer.